# Using isPrimitive or isArray on Introspector Values

Tags: java, introspection

I am using introspection to retrieve a beans get methods and i'd like to be able to determine if the result is an Array or a Primitive, but I always get a false response. Even when I know that the type is an ArrayList. On that same note, will isArray() work for all types of Arrays such as primitive Array, ArrayList etc?

```
Class<?> className = bean1.getClass();
ArrayList<ComparatorValue> updateIndexes = new ArrayList<ComparatorValue>();            
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(className);
PropertyDescriptor classProperties[] = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();


for(int i=0; i<classProperties.length; i++) {
    Method getter = classProperties[i].getReadMethod();
    System.out.println(getter.invoke(bean1).getClass().isArray()); //Always false.
    System.out.println(getter.invoke(bean1).getClass().isPrimitive()); //Always false.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the method, a primitive return value will get boxed into its wrapper class.

```
getter.invoke(bean1).getClass().isPrimitive()
```

Since you are calling `getClass` on the wrapped return value, `isPrimitve` will return false. You can retrieve the actual return type by calling `getter.getReturnType()`.

Answer (score 2):

Collections (ArrayList, etc) are not arrays. They're objects that are part of [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Only arrays are arrays;

```
int[] foo = new int[5];
Object[] bar = new Object[4];
```

*Those* are arrays. - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Understood. Still, the isPrimitive() does not work on fields that I know are primitive types such as int or String.

Comment: Erm, `String` is an Object, not a primitive. As for `int`, that is a primitive but without seeing what you're doing I can't point out what's wrong :) Are you sure you don't have an `Integer` ?

Comment: Basically I am trying to test if the value of each getter in the bean is an ArrayList, an Array, an Integer or int, String etc etc. If it is a type such as an array my code will need to further loop through it, otherwise if its not then I will handle the result (which is why I need to check). Is there a better way to verify the values type?